# Compare 2D lists and return index where they differ

Tags: python, list, indexof

I want to compare the elements of two similar lists and return the index where they differ.

The lists will only differ at one position.

```
def coord(a,b):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if a[i][j] != b[i][j]:
                return # index where they differ


a = [[0,0,2],[2,1,1],[0,1,0]]
b = [[2,0,2],[2,1,1],[0,1,0]]

print(coord(a,b))
```

Preferred output: `[0,0]`

Comment: Just `return [i, j]`?

Comment: Well that was embarrassing. Maybe I need a break. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will return every index at which list differs

```
temp= []
def coord(a,b):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if a[i][j] != b[i][j]:
                temp.append([i,j])
    print temp

a = [[0,0,2],[2,1,1],[0,1,0]]
b = [[2,0,2],[2,1,1],[0,1,0]]

coord(a,b)
```